# why can't object literal call toString() method like {}.toString() cause error?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

When object literal calls `toString()` method like `{}.toString()` will cause syntax error, but when array literal call `toString()` it is OK. And when I assign the object literal to a variable, then when it call the `toString()` method will be OK. Why? For example:

```
var o = {};
o.toString();  // OK

{}.toString(); 
// > Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
[1, 2, 3].toString(); // OK
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because `{}` is seen as a valid block first, instead of a literal in that context.

In simple terms - consider that line is interpreted from left to right, encounters `{` and therefore expects that a block has started. When the block ends, it encounters `.` and that identifier is not allowed there.

If you were to use `({}).toString()` that will work.

This is because the line starts with `(` and therefore expects an expression, it correctly identifies the `{}` as an expression which is evaluated to an empty object and therefore '.toString()` is allowed.

If `{}` is used in another context - e.g. in your example `o = {}` this is correctly interpreted as an empty object because is's on the right-hand side of an assignment (after `=`).

Note that in ES6 there is a similar but more common/practical situation where understanding this is important - when returning objects in one-liner arrow functions, e.g.

```
[1,2,3,4].map(val => { v: val, isOdd: v % 2 === 1 }) // ERROR
[1,2,3,4].map(val => ({ v: val, isOdd: v % 2 === 1 })) // OK
```

Comment: Good answer! Can you explain it in detail and why does this happen? Thanks.

Comment: [Grouping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) has a higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) than [member access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation).